# CSRF validation error when use custom upload handler in django

Tags: django, forms, upload, handler, csrf

I'm developing a progress bar for upload files using [this upload handler](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/678/), it's a bit older, since 2008 have no modifications so maybe has been disregarded however this solution is used a lot around the web for this problem, specifically to monitor an upload file, the question is simple, when I make a request and I set up previously this handler, firstly, for method `GET` retrieve the form:

```
<form id="formUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/progressbar/uploadfile" method="post" class="form">
{% csrf_token %}
{% bootstrap_form form %}
{% buttons %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Submit
    </button>
{% endbuttons %}
```

`csrf_token` always is generated so when I make a `submit`for the form, debugging, always goes to `handler_raw_input` before check the `POST` request from view so there's no `csrf_token` can validate against the request and throw a nice 403 csrf token error validation.

View:

```
def upload_file(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = UploadFile(file=request.FILES['file'])
        instance.save()            
else:
    form = UploadFileForm()
return render_to_response('index.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How can I tell upload handler to assign `csrf_token` for validation? According to django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/file-uploads/) only uploads handlers can be modified before `request.POST` and `reques.FILES` and csrf is managing via `POST` forms.

Any ideas or people in same situation?

Regards!

Comment: why use that upload handler? is very old. Check in your broswer console the sended request, and check if the csrf token have been sent.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you referenced it looks like you have to mark the progress updates as excempt (@csrf_exempt) and the actual file handler as protected (
@csrf_protect). So for your upload handler I would try:

```py
@csrf_exempt
def upload_progress(request):
    """
    Return JSON object with information about the progress of an upload.
    """
...

@csrf_protect
def upload_file(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
...
```

You should obviously test this by changing the CSRF field in the form using JavaScript to make sure it fails as expected.